# How to Setup Sonarcube scanner for Xcode/Objective-C iOS Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube. I find the documents given in the portal has very less information about setting it up in Xcode/Objective-C. Can anyone help in instructions for Setting/Installing sonarQube scanner.

I use this below steps for Android project. I need the steps for iOS which I am not able to find

```
1. Copy sonar cube from LS Path : \\ipaddress\Mobility\LS\Tools\Sonar
2. Paste it in C:\Program Files (x86)\
3. Run sonar-runner
4. Set Environment variable path: C:\Program Files (x86)\sonar-runner-2.4\bin
5. Configure Project : Example :
    sonar.projectName= 
    sonar.projectKey=
    sonar.host.url=
    sonar.sources=app/src/main/java/
    sonar.login=
    sonar.password=
    sonar.projectVersion=
in sonar-project file.

6. Paste that file inside our project folder
7. Open command prompt and go to projectso path.
7. copy paste the following in command prompt:
    sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=app/src -Dsonar.java.binaries=app/build/outputs/apk -Dsonar.java.libraries=app/libs/*.jar
```

I am getting the below error

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to
>   execute SonarQube     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)   at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from
>   server    at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getBootstrapIndex(Jars.java:100)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getScannerEngineFiles(Jars.java:76)
>     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Status
>   returned by url [http://ipaddress/batch/index] is not valid:
>   [407]     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:115)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
>     at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getBootstrapIndex(Jars.java:96)
>     ... 12 more ERROR:

Comment: Can you be clearer about what is missing from [the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarCFamily+for+Objective-C)?

Comment: i am not clear in finding sonar QUBE installation steps for objective C. Can u help me by providing it

Comment: You mean [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin)?

Comment: You can check this SonarQube iOS integration. https://medium.com/@pranay.urkude/sonarqube-integration-with-ios-b76df8405014